# getting values of auto generated input fields angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I was stuck with this problem for a while now, where i am trying to get values for an auto generated input fields so one click can get all the values of all the generated inputs at once.

This is the part of html where the inputs get created :

```
<div ng-controller="IngredientController as ctrl" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="ingredientgroup in ctrl.ingredientContainer">
        <div  ng-repeat="group in ingredientgroup">
            <div ng-if="!group.groupId"><h3>{{group.name}}</h3></div>
            <div ng-if="group.groupId">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>
                        {{group.name}}<input type="text" class="form-control">
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$dismiss()">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close(ctrl.product)">ok</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the array structure.
Declare a `$scope` variable `myInput` in your controller

```
$scope.myInput = [];
```

Use the variable inside your `ng-repeat`

```
{{group.name}}<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="myInput[{{group.groupId}}]">
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help it worked. but i wanted to know something if i am planning to access the id  of the groups and the data using a for loop isn't that going to make the application slower the more data there is ?

Comment: Yes, but a single for loop will have a negligible delay. Since you have no other possibility to read dynamically generated data, you can go with it. Your `$scope.myInput` will be an array that you can use to read data.